# Laravel proc_open(): fork failed

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error in laravel after a `composer update`

> Uncaught ErrorException: proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable in vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php:127
>
> $process = proc_open('stty -a | grep columns', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null, array('suppress_errors' => true));

Many forums and other questions in StackOverflow said that problem is occurring due to low server memory but there is enough memory available.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe it simply  has to do with permissions? Just a guess though.

Comment: It is also possible that you run out of file descriptors, can not spawn any new threads, and so on. So you could run out of something else than memory, too.

Comment: did you resolve? seeing this as well

Comment: No, I searched the whole project, files and libraries ... I had to re-config the project @caro